# Magento - prevent from manual attribute changing

Tags: magento

I have this one attribute which is saved by the Magento API. I want to make this attribute read only in administrator view. In another words I want to prohibit manual changes of this attribute.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/235623/#t341864

I guess this would help.